# Как определить ip виртуальной машины(VirtualBox/Ubuntu) в Windows (хостовая)? Как из Ubuntu (гостевая) я знаю, но не знаю можно ли узнать из Windows?

Tags: сеть, ip, виртуальная-машина

### Дано.
Хостовая машина: Windows 7
Гостевая машина: Ubuntu 20.04
Программа виртуальной машины: VirtualBox 5.2
Тип подключения: Сетевой мост

Найти.
Могу ли я, используя командную строку Windows(на которую установлена виртуальная машина), узнать IP адрес этой самой виртуальной машины (Ubuntu). Через саму виртуальную машину - знаю как (ip a), а вот как через Windows? Команда (в Windows) ipconfig не показывает нужную IP.

Comment: если mac-адрес известен, можно попробовать `arp -a`